# How to convert mkv to dvd or avi

Tags: video, conversion

I have some mkv files, and while Totem plays them perfectly, when i use Devede to burn them to dvd it all gets messed up: the video is ok, but the audio is out of sync.

I did see that Devede does write my dixv avi files correctly to disk.

So i am thinking what the best way could be to convert my mkv for playback on dvd?

I was thinking maybe converting them to avi first? But i did not find a good way for that to happen.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Related http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820035

Comment: the question asks to convert mkv to avi but the accepted answer is for the other way around

Comment: As far as I remember, it did the job. If I read it know, it seems misleading indeed :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is the best video converter tool I know.

From the [details](http://handbrake.fr/details.php) page:

> **Supported Sources:**
>
> Any DVD-like source: VIDEO_TS folder, DVD image or real DVD (unencrypted--protection >methods including CSS are not supported internally and must be handled externally with >third-party software and libraries), and some .VOB and .TS files
> Most any multimedia file it can get libavformat to read and libavcodec to decode.
>
> **Outputs:**
>
> File format: MP4 and MKV
> Video: MPEG-4, H.264, or Theora
> Audio: AAC, CoreAudio AAC (OS X Only), MP3, or Vorbis. AC-3 pass-through, DTS pass-thorugh >(MKV only)

You can install it via Software Center or `sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk` [if you use their PPA:](https://edge.launchpad.net/%7Estebbins/+archive/handbrake-snapshots)

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu UBUNTU_VERSION main`
`deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu UBUNTU_VERSION main`

Comment: An easier method to install the ppa is to enter `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots` at a command line.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I can add the repository, in @fluteflute's way, but if i type `sudo apt-get install handbrake` i get the error `E: Couldn't find package handbrake`.

Comment: @nathanvda Did you run `sudo apt-get update` after adding the repository?

Comment: That did help, but i got this in return: `$ sudo apt-get install handbrake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package handbrake is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package handbrake has no installation candidate`. 

I am going to try to build from source instead.

Comment: maybe you should try downloading through the site the, before venturing to compiling sources.

Comment: @nathanvda: Try going into synaptic and searching for handbrake, it's possible the package name isn't 'handbrake' precisely, it may be 'handbrake-gui' or something along those lines.

Comment: @nathanvda I added the PPA and was able to install using `handbrake-gtk` as package name. Updated the answer with the corrected package name

Comment: Compiling manually was not that hard (very well described on their site), but i am only able to convert to m4v and i had a problem with the subtitles. I did do a `apt-cache search handbrake` and found nothing at the time (now it works :).

Comment: Note that HandBrake doesn't support AVI output anymore: http://handbrake.fr/news.php?article=10

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I agree Handbrake is nice.

However, if you want a simple and easy app, you can use **MobileMediaConvertor**. It almost converts anything. [Website](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm)

**Arista Transcoder** from software center is good too.

Comment: Those look very interesting. I am going to try those out.

Answer (score 3):

There is an option called convert/save in vlc "media" option. I think the shortcut key is ctrl + R. It surely converts to mp4. Will this help:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxanswers-discussion-27/discussion-avi-to-dvd-360138/

Answer (score 2):

I think vlc supports converting to avi and i think it plays mkv as well.

In `media` menu there is an option for `convert/save`

[VLC Transcode](https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode/)

Comment: It does play mkv, I was not aware it was able to convert video.

Comment: How can you use vlc to convert video?

Answer (score 2):

For the old "command line magic" I like using [mencoder](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mencoder), which is part of [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/info.html). Then I use [dvdwizard](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dvdwizard) to make the DVD.

The basic command line to convert anything into a PAL 16:9 dvd vob file

```
mencoder <name of input file> -vf scale=720:576 -ofps 25 -ovc lavc -vf-pre scale=720:-3,expand=720:::::16/9:16,harddup -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg2video:keyint=15:vrc_buf_size=1835:vrc_maxrate=9800:vbitrate=2500:aspect=16/9:vstrict=0 -of mpeg -mpegopts format=dvd -srate = 48000 -o <name of output file>
```

Of course I never write all that, I have a script that wraps all that and gives me a few "simple" options for things like 2 pass encoding, frame rate, audio codec, removing video noise, and sharpening the picture...

The script is [avi2vob](http://paste.ubuntu.com/828007/).

To convert a bunch of videos to 24fps 16:9 video, with 2 pass encoding and video sharpening

```
avi2vob -f -2 -s1 -d video1.avi video2.mkv video3.flc
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I convert .mkv videos to .avi to play them on my gothic dvd player. The best program to do this seamlessly (according to me, atleast) is **Avidemux**. :))

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once; If I remember correctly, I fixed it by checking "file already has AC3 audio" or similar in the DeVeDe menu (advanced options). That is, if your MKV has AC3 audio in it ;)

Answer (score -1):

Personally recommend three solutions to convert MKV to AVI.

**[HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/)**: it's free and has the feature of converting MKV to AVI.

**Cons**:

1. HandBrake is too professional to handle for most people;
2. It doesn't support MOV as output format.

**a video tool** which can [convert MKV to AVI](http://www.faasoft.com/articles/convert-mkv-to-avi-windows-mac.html). It's not expensive and runs well on Mavericks and Windows 8. Most of all, the converted video will keep the same quality with the original video.