# How to convert .mkv file into .mp4 file losslessly?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, mkv, avidemux

I need to convert a video file from Matroska container into mp4 container. Matroska file contains one h.264 video track and one AC3 sound track. It should be possible to do this losslessly, but how to do it with native Ubuntu tools?

Transcoding is not an option.

Comment: See this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3287/how-to-convert-mkv-to-dvd-or-avi).

Comment: this is especially a solution for converting Matroska files that won't play in a Samsung TV, to files that are compatible with it

Comment: Over the years I've found this very useful as `Chromecast` supports `H.264` with `AAC` or `MP3` in an `MP4` container. It is very easy to stream videos from your computer to `Chromecast` if you have Chrome with the Google cast extension. Just drag and drop an `MP4` with correct stream encodings to a browser window and start streaming.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest tool for that is `ffmpeg`, or `avconv` from the `libav-tools` package. Libav is a fork of FFmpeg, which Ubuntu switched to for a few years until Ubuntu 15.04. It is one of the backends for many of the GUI tools mentioned in other answers.

Changing container without re-enconding content could not be simpler:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec copy output.mp4
```

- It auto-detects a Matroska to MP4 container conversion based on input/output filenames.
- `-codec copy` stream copies, or "re-muxes", the streams from the input to the output without re-encoding. Think of it like a copy and paste between containers.
- Default stream selection behavior is to select only one stream per stream type. For example, if your input has two video streams and one audio stream then only the video stream with the largest frame size will be selected. Add `-map 0` if you want to select all streams from the input.
- Some containers may not support some formats. So check if your chosen *container* format, be it `mkv`, `mp4` or even `avi` has support for all the *content* in your files (video, audio, subtitles, data, etc). For example, `mp4` does not support SubRip subtitles (`.srt` files).

Comment: To transcode the audio to AAC, leaving the video as AVC: `avconv -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a libfaac output.mp4` (I used ffmpeg, I assume avconv has the same command line args here)

Comment: @camh: What you said works, but please note 2 things: 1) It will leave video as-is, regardless if it is AVC or something else; 2) It will not only convert audio to AAC but also the container format from mkv to mp4

Comment: If you want to transfer both the video and audio (both losslessly) and for it not to choke on subtitles then: `avconv -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy -sn output.mp4`.  MP4 supports the most of the common audio formats used in MKVs including MP3 and AAC.

Comment: Do you know if this will work for multiple sound tracks?

Comment: Yes @BillO'Dwyer. `-codec copy` means *all* tracks (formally called "streams", which can be audio, video, subtitles, etc) will be losslessly copied to the new container. So it will change the *container* from `mkv` to `mp4` without changing the *content*.

Comment: Thanks @MestreLion, I tried it, but for some reason the subtitles didn't stick... I'll play around and see if I can't fix it :)

Comment: @BillO'Dwyer: That's because `mp4` container format does not support soft subtitles (`.srt` files)

Comment: @MestreLion Fair enough... Final question: do you know if this can be done as a batch process?

Comment: @BillO'Dwyer: sure, with a bit of bash scripting. something like `for video in *.mkv; do avconv -i "$video" -c copy -sn "${video//.*}.mp4"; done`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: amazing edit, looks *so* much better now!

Comment: from [here](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=39226) I got a tip to use like this `avconv -i [input] -map 0:v -map 0:a:1 [other options] [outputfile]` in my case it worked perfectly as the 2nd audio stream was what I needed!

Comment: @AquariusPower: just be aware that the OP does not want to remap the streams: he wants to convert the container only and keep all streams.

Comment: @MestreLion that's the point, I tried to use the simple command to convert, without the -map, I ended up in a video with only one audio stream (it didnt bring both audio streams), and the wrong one. So that command was what worked, by selecting the 2nd audio stream, having now only one but correct audio stream.

Comment: @AquariusPower: have you tried simply with `-map 0` to get both audio streams? As I said in the answer: *"Default stream selection behavior is to select only one stream per stream type"*

Comment: @MestreLion I see now... thx!

Comment: Use `-c:s mov_text` option if you need to keep eg. `srt` subtitle track.

Comment: @camh: FFmpeg removed libfaac support in 2016, instead using native, built-in FFmpeg AAC encoder. "ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4"

Comment: @chiappa: is this really needed when using `-codec copy` and/or `-map 0`? If so, I should add this to the answer

Answer (score 31):

#### Get needed software

```
sudo apt-get install gpac mkvtoolnix
```

#### Extract video and audio from matroska file

First you need to check what tracks the matroska file contains with

`mkvmerge --identify video.mkv`

```
File 'video.mkv': container: Matroska
Track ID 1: video (V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC)
Track ID 2: audio (A_AC3)
```

Then extract video and audio according to their tracks with:

`mkvextract tracks video.mkv 1:video.h264 2:audio.ac3`

```
Extracting track 1 with the CodecID 'V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC' to the file 'video.h264'. Container format: AVC/h.264 elementary stream
Extracting track 2 with the CodecID 'A_AC3' to the file 'audio.ac3'. Container format: Dolby Digital (AC3)
Progress: 100%
```

#### Mux audio and video into mp4 containter

`MP4Box -fps 24 -add video.h264 -add audio.ac3 video.mp4`

```
AVC-H264 import - frame size 1280 x 720 at 24.000 FPS
Import results: 31671 samples - Slices: 5672 I 125048 P 122648 B - 32288 SEI - 4936 IDR
AC3 import - sample rate 48000 - 6 channels
Saving to video.mp4: 0.500 secs Interleaving
```

I had to add `-fps 24` option because `MP4Box` didn't detect video fps correctly. Depending on usage `AC3` audio track should be re-encoded into something else before muxing.

Now you have remuxed streams from matroska container into mp4 container without losing any quality.

EDIT:
MP4 doesn't officially support AC3 audio so the audio track should be converted into a supported format (eg. AAC, MP3) if you want the file to be playable with something else than VLC.

Comment: Will this work with subtitle tracks?

Comment: My case: I had a .webm audio then first I converted to mp4: follow this question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/323944/convert-webm-to-other-formats

Comment: `ffmpeg` does it very straight.

Answer (score 15):

**You can use Avidemux**

It has good GUI interface.

When converting from mkv to mp4 it is not re-encoded.

The convertion is done within a minute (for a 60-min video).

1. `sudo apt-get install avidemux`
2. Open the mkv file in avidemux.
3. Select safe mode if prompted.
4. Leave the video as copy.
5. Choose File-> Properties. Check if the audio codec is `aac`.

   1. If audio codec is NOT aac, select `aac(faac)`.
   2. Otherwise, leave it as `copy`. (Sometimes using this option the audio may
      be out of sync or distorted, in that case select `aac(faac)` instead.)
6. Select `mp4` for format.
7. Select save, choose location and type a filename with `.mp4` as the extension.

**Note:** Sometimes (~10% chance) it may fail. Then use `handbrake(re-encode)`.

**Note2:** there are two links which help you:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/avidemux-free-video-editor-designed-for-simple-cutting-filtering-and-encoding-tasks.html

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-convert-mkv-file-into-mp4-file-using-avidemux.html

Comment: Worked like a charm. I had sync problems following the accepted answer, but not with this one.

Comment: works very well

Answer (score 7):

[image]

You can use my application, [dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html). Just leave "**copy**" for both streams checked (no transcoding)  and put **.mp4** to the output file name. That's it. Very simple.
http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html

Comment: Thank you for this great tool! - Note: on multiple occasions, when the mkv had internal subs, I had to change the codec to `mov_text`.

Answer (score 1):

Using **ffmpeg** i write a python script that will convert all the mkv files of the current directory to mp4 files as converting them one by is annoying.

Can use it if needed.

[Convert MKV to MP4](https://github.com/jspw/Little-Fun-Stuffs/tree/master/mkv%20to%20mp4%20converter)

Answer (score -3):

You can try [HANDBRAKE](http://handbrake.fr/details.php) by adding its PPA by typing this code into the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
```

Comment: This seems to be a video transcoder. I do not want to compress the video track again as it is already in h.264 format.

Comment: Handbrake is a great transcoder, but I would never use it for file format conversion.

Comment: I absolutely love Handbreak, but unfortunately it only works losslessly for audio (and subtitles). I couldn't find a way to copy the video without transcoding it, and the OP specifically requested lossless format conversion.

Answer (score -3):

Since MPEG Part 14 supports h.264 and AC3 natively without transcoding, you can simply rename the file so it has an `.mp4` extension instead of a `.mkv` extension.

Comment: It might support the codecs inside, but that doesn't mean it will work in an application that doesn't understand Matroska. This would only work if the application supports Matroska and looks at the magic number instead of the extension.

Comment: Renaming the file will not convert the container format, and it might confuse the application (and users).  As @ArdaXi said, the application would still need to support Matroska to play it.