# Joining Two MKV files in Ubuntu?

Tags: mkv, join, handbrake

I have an opera that I'm ripping to my computer in MKV format with Handbrake. This opera is on two discs. Is there a way to join the resulting MKV's together? They will have the same bitrate, resolution, etc. If I do this, can I keep chapters from both MKV files organized? And, since I have subtitles in the file (not burnt in), will they still stay intact?

I'm not too sure if this question is off-topic or not. If it is, feel more than free to delete it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the resolution of the videos are same, then you can use avidemux to join them

Comment: This method was easier than aking1012's, so that's the only reason that I accepted this answer.

Answer (score 56):

Recommended way is to use **mkvtoolnix**

```
sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix mkvtoolnix-gui
```

- Start mmg (graphical user interface for mkvmerge)
- "Add" the first file
- "Append" the second one, third, fourth, ...
- Set output name in the textbox at the bottom
- "Start muxing"

Subtitles are preserved and properly concatenated, so are audio and video.
Chapters can be edited in the resulting file with mmg.

This procedure creates a properly muxed file. 
Any problems should be mentioned in the "log"-window in mmg.
You can even set and name audio and subtitle tracks with the correct language codes and Annotations like "Forced" or "Directors Commentary".

If you plan to do this repeatedly on different files you better use the command line version **mkvmerge** ("mkvmerge --help")

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv input1.mkv +input2.mkv
```

Comment: I don't find the append button in mkvtoolnix-gui currently. The command line version seems to be the simpler and faster way to concat mkv files. Note the `+` character to append video files instead of merge.

Comment: I just used `mkvmerge` (without the plus sign) with no issues to combine an mkv video file and an mp3 audio file that had to be downloaded separately from a website. It rocks!

Answer (score 17):

Use this command in terminal, to merge two separate '.mkv-files' into one.

```
mkvmerge -o newfile.mkv part1.mkv +part2.mkv
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me.

Comment: The higher rated answer actually tells you how to _get_ mkvmerge...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to combine video is to use a container format that supports concatenation and re-indexing, like mpg.  Then you can just `cat file1 file2 > file3` and re-index with ffmpeg.

The steps in your case would be:
Convert from mkv to mpg
Concatenate
Re-index
Change back to mkv if you like

If it's just audio, you could use a more easily editable file type...like wav, mp3, or ogg until you've got your final output.  Then you can use loads of tools to join audio.  Sox or FFmpeg come to mind.

Comment: I'm in the process of ripping disc 2 now...whenever I finish, I'll give this a try...let's hope it works! :)

Comment: Nice that only ffmpeg is required for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dmMediaConverter](https://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html) to do this. It is very simple and works well. There is a mode of the program for joining `MKV` files and uses `ffmpeg` under the hood. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/927621/372592) answer for more.

Answer (score 0):

[LosslessCut](https://www.mifi.no/losslesscut/) can also merge files.

Go to *Tools > Merge*.

It has an option to include all of streams in case such multiple streams per file are present. By default it selects the "default" (that is first/main) streams of each file.