# Trying to convert MKV to MP4 with avconv, failing

Tags: mp4, mkv, avconv

I am trying to convert an MKV file to MP4 to be compatible with my PS3. I am using:

```
avconv -i file.mkv -c copy file.mp4
```

It fails and I get the following error:

```
[mp4 @ 0x8a17c00] pts < dts in stream 0
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

The file is h264 video and ac3 audio.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50433/how-to-convert-mkv-file-into-mp4-file-losslessly) question may give you some pointers. See answer #2

Comment: That question is where I originally found how to do the conversion. There is no mention of errors though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: After much trial and error i got it to work using: `avconv -i file.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy file.mp4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that

```
avconv -i file.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy file.mp4
```

is the correct command. You need to specify the codec copy property for the streams you want to copy separately.

Comment: That should be correct. At least that you need to specify video and audio codec. If `-c:a` is not accepted `-codec:a` and `-acodec` should work, same goes for video.

Answer (score 4):

#### Get needed software

```
sudo apt-get install gpac mkvtoolnix
```

#### Extract video and audio from matroska file

First you need to check what tracks the matroska file contains with

`mkvmerge --identify video.mkv`

```
File 'video.mkv': container: Matroska
Track ID 1: video (V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC)
Track ID 2: audio (A_AC3)
```

Then extract video and audio according to their tracks with:

`mkvextract tracks video.mkv 1:video.h264 2:audio.ac3`

```
Extracting track 1 with the CodecID 'V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC' to the file 'video.h264'. Container format: AVC/h.264 elementary stream
Extracting track 2 with the CodecID 'A_AC3' to the file 'audio.ac3'. Container format: Dolby Digital (AC3)
Progress: 100%
```

#### Mux audio and video into mp4 containter

`MP4Box -fps 24 -add video.h264 -add audio.ac3 video.mp4`

```
AVC-H264 import - frame size 1280 x 720 at 24.000 FPS
Import results: 31671 samples - Slices: 5672 I 125048 P 122648 B - 32288 SEI - 4936 IDR
AC3 import - sample rate 48000 - 6 channels
Saving to video.mp4: 0.500 secs Interleaving
```

I had to add `-fps 24` option because `MP4Box` didn't detect video fps correctly. Depending on usage `AC3` audio track should be re-encoded into something else before muxing.

Now you have remuxed streams from matroska container into mp4 container without losing any quality.

EDIT:
MP4 doesn't officially support AC3 audio so the audio track should be converted into a supported format (eg. AAC, MP3) if you want the file to be playable with something else than VLC.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for muxing mp4 along with m4a. The usual **ffmpeg** [commands](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/300841-CLI-to-mux-merge-MP4-video-and-AAC-audio?p=1839658&viewfull=1#post1839658) for encoding didn't worked.Tried MP4Box & it worked like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **winff-gtk2** it solved my the problem! To install:

```
sudo apt install winff-gtk2
```

.

Comment: avconf is dead for a very long time. Still, winff is based on ffmpeg , not on avconf.  And the question was about avconf (which never did it get quiet right) . ffmpeg is back for long time now...