# Streaming Video Files to PS3

Tags: streaming, rygel

## Project: I would like to stream my home dvds to my PS3 system using Rygel.

A) I would like to use handbrake to produce exceptional copies of my home dvd's in the .mkv format  (Or if an experienced user in dvdripping/transcoding could suggest a better solution in either dvd::rip or handbrake I am willing to listen, space is not a concern).

B) Share and stream those movies from my ubuntu 14.04 pc to my ps3 system, preferrably by using Rygel as opposed to ps3mediaserver.

### DVD ripping programs used so far:

#### DVD::RIP

Excellent ripping, produces exceptional .vob copies of dvds.  Not able to control default language, most dvd's produce multiple .vob files, some are english some are french and of course some are spanish. When I use VLC to view the files I am able to set the audio track to the appropriate one (english), hinting that all audio streams are there but not being accessed properly (for lack of better words).  This is not the case when accessing through rygel on the PS3 system, as well this setting is not available on the PS3 system I believe (either way, it would still be irritating having to constantly switch the tracks).  Transcoding is probably where I am going wrong, I am aware of the different container formats and codecs although I do not know all the technical specifications that seem to be required to produce exceptional .avi or .mpg4 files similar to the .vob that dvd::rip produced in the first place.

#### HANDBRAKE

Love the simplicity, appears to produce exceptional .mkv formats (does not seem to be a native media format on ps3 systems.

### DLNA compliant servers

#### ps3mediaserver

Oh wow, the problems so far..... there was a time when this worked flawlessly for me.....sigh.  Other than that seems to work as it should but when I stream my movie I get one of two errors.  Either the standard 800288E1 error on the ps3 system or the movie comes in as it should (quality wise) but the sounds is just loud static.  Played the same file through Rygel and it works as it should (quality wise) and with the normal sound.
I tested the avi file locally on the ps3 system and it plays fine which suggests a transcoding error.  Here is the error when the movie fails to play completely incase someone may know how to fix it.  Hopefully it is the relevant data.

```
INFO  2014-04-21 13:27:42.263 [pool-15-thread-1]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
INFO  2014-04-21 13:27:45.671 [New I/O server worker #1-2] Starting transcode/remux of ZOHAN-001.avi
ERROR 2014-04-21 13:27:45.855 [mencoder-3] Error initializing process: 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mencoder": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at net.pms.io.ProcessWrapperImpl.run(ProcessWrapperImpl.java:183) ~[pms.jar:1.90.1]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:45.952 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:46.453 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:46.954 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:47.455 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:47.956 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:48.458 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:48.959 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:49.460 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:49.961 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
WARN  2014-04-21 13:27:50.462 [New I/O server worker #1-2] External input stream instance is null... sounds not good, waiting 500ms
ERROR 2014-04-21 13:27:50.964 [New I/O server worker #1-2] There is no inputstream to return for ZOHAN-001.avi - [MEncoder Video]
```

#### Rygel

Works great, simple to use and the Rygel preferences app makes things easy to share directories.  Wont stream the .mkv files though.  I run rygel from the terminal so here is there error when I try to stream an mkv file through rygel

```
scruffy@Scrffy11:~$ rygel
Rygel-Message: rygel-main.vala:87: Rygel v starting…
^Cscruffy@Scrffy11:~$ rygel
Rygel-Message: rygel-main.vala:87: Rygel v starting…
Rygel-Message: New plugin 'MediaExport' available
MediaExport-Message: 'file:///home/scruffy/Videos' harvested
MediaExport-Message: 'file:///home/scruffy/dvdrip-data' harvested
Rygel-Message: rygel-thumbnailer.vala:132: No D-Bus thumbnailer available

(rygel:7914): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 793 was not found when attempting to remove it

(rygel:7914): Rygel-WARNING **: rygel-http-request.vala:105: Could not create a transcoder configuration. Your GStreamer installation might be missing a plug-in
```

So to me it says it all right there, rygel executes gstreamer and an appropriate plug-in for the transcoding but I appear to be missing a plug-in.  So I found out that I need the mastrokamux plugin for gstreamer which is in an apparent "good" category (not sure how to find out what plugins I may have already or how to get new ones).  So here's the general problems that I hope someone may be able to help with.

1. How do I add the mastrokamux plugin (codec) to gstreamer?

   a. Is this possible without having to rebuild(recompile) gstreamer?
2. Even if I successfully add the mastrokamux plugin will rygel know how to call it?  Or will I need to also recompile that as well?

So in summary:

A) I would like to use handbrake to produce exceptional copies of my home dvd's in the .mkv format  (Or if an experienced user in dvdripping/transcoding could suggest a better solution in either dvd::rip or handbrake I am willing to listen, space is not a concern).

B) Share and stream those movies from my ubuntu 14.04 pc to my ps3 system, preferrably by using Rygel as opposed to ps3mediaserver.

Sounded like a simple project...what happened? ;)

Comment: Why not encode in a format the PS3 supports natively, and serve with a simpler server like minidlna?

Comment: I will give minidlna a try.
I figured the native format for the ps3 is the best option as well however it comes back to me not encoding the video format properly.  If you would be kind enough to suggest the best settings when doing this in dvd::rip it would be VERY much appreciated.
Basically what goes wrong is I'll rip the dvds into .vob's first then do the transcoding (as suggested by many dvd::rip forums/tutorials).  I'll test the .vobs on the ps3 via dlna and its beautiful but when I transcode........is choppy.
Thanks again for the suggestion! :)

Comment: The best format I've found for playback on PS3 is mp4 using x264 as the codec. Unfortunately, I think the Debian Handbrake package (which is what is in Ubuntu), disables several features due to DFSG guidelines.

Comment: Those are the settings I am using in handbrake but it is only giving me the option of producing *.mkv format......hmmm I don't think I've tried streaming .mkv through ps3mediaserver yet.  I will try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found for this is to use HandBrake to copy the DVD with the appropriate settings, thanks Dobey for the suggested settings, they work great.

Then just convert the .mkv format to .mp4 using MP4Box.

I've found that if anyone would like to use this method you will most likely need to install the required library files and binaries to read encrypted/protected dvd's (as I'm sure you're aware).

I then stuck with `rygel` as it just works the way I want it to.

I attempted to try out `minidlna` but the apt-get repository couldn't locate the package, don't care why at this point.

I tried `ps3mediaserver` as well and it continues to transcode even when I set the option not to and continues to produce static sound (not acceptable).

And by the way, its all wireless and works great, IN FACT the transfer rate is much less in Rygel than it is in ps3mediaserver without sacrificing quality.

I hope this helps anyone who may decide to embark on a similar project.

Here is the link that helped me with the transcode operation from .mkv -> .mp4

[Trying to convert MKV to MP4 with avconv, failing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243582/trying-to-convert-mkv-to-mp4-with-avconv-failing)