# how to convert video files

Tags: 12.04

Is there a easy way to convert .mkv files into .avi files with ubuntu? I have tried downloading apps but none of which seem to work. 
                                      Thanks

Comment: For many other alternatives see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50433/how-to-convert-mkv-file-into-mp4-file-losslessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Handbrake**](http://handbrake.fr/features.php) is the best tool for converting .mkv files to .avi files in ubuntu.Run the following commands on terminal to install handbrake in Ubuntu 12.04,

Edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file,

```
 sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following lines to the opened sources.list file,

```
 deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu precise main 
 deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu precise main
```

Then update the repositories,

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

Run this command to install handbrake,

```
 sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

Comment: can we use it for converting flv's to mp4? or other formats ..

Comment: yes,you can convert.

Answer (score 1):

Get WinFF:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paul-climbing/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winff
```

Optionally:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```

In WinFF, choose a preset like "Widescreen XVID", then load the video bitrate, framerate, resolution and audio settings with those of the MKV file (you can get them by right-clicking the file and selecting Properties > Audio/Video). Do a search on Wikipedia for "Aspect Ratio" to get the right aspect ratio settings for different resolutions. Converting a 45 minute 720P MKV to AVI takes about 20 minutes on a Core i7 with 24GB RAM.

Source: 
https://code.google.com/archive/p/winff/wikis/UbuntuInstallation.wiki

Comment: Easy way : once installed, type winff to launch the GUI. Open the file you want to convert and choose avi as output. You are offered a choice in the menu below this choice, I select the first option "MS compatible avi". Then my avi can be run on anything. The only drawback is that it's a bit slow.

Answer (score 0):

AS Handbrake doesn't support AVI Output anymore you can do this very rapidly via the command line with `avconv` like this:

`avconv -i infile.mkv -codec copy outfile.avi`

By using -codec copy you are changing the container only without the need to re-encode the movie. Note: Depending on the codecs in use in the original file you may need to install the Ubuntu restricted extras package first. You can do this via either software center or via the CLI from a terminal with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Source: Experience

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg
https://www.ffmpeg.org/

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy output.avi
```

source: https://superuser.com/questions/227338/how-to-convert-an-mkv-to-avi-with-minimal-loss

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you were to [edit] it to include Instructions for installation of ffmpeg as it's no longer included in the distributions.