# Avconv doesn't convert .MKV to .MP4 no errors output file 0KB

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I understand that this is SIMILAR to questions asked before and using those posts I have actually got the file process going however when it finishes (with out errors mind you) the .mp4 is a 0KB file and when opened using movie player it says stream contains no data.

code used to convert:

```
avconv -i movie.mkv -map 0 -strict experimental movie.mp4
```

also

```
avconv -i movie.mkv -map 0 movie.mp4
```

also

```
avconv -i movie.mkv -codec copy movie.mp4
```

lastly

```
avconv -i movie.mkv -c:v copy -c:a libfaac movie.mp4
```

they all end with this.

```
video:400835kB audio:85478kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000000%
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert .mkv file into .mp4 file losslessly?](http://askubuntu.com/q/50433/283843)

Comment: I looked at that one for the initial code, however that thread was successful and the guy converted it with out problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Ubuntu restricted extras package. You may be missing some of the required codecs. You can install through the software center as shown below:[image: SoftCenter-Restricted-extras]

Or you can install via the command line with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll give it a try next time I try to convert something (honestly might be a while I've since I've changed jobs.)

Comment: Your welcome! I hope it helps you or someone else with similar issues.